# unable to add logging to my asp.net core8.0 console application "ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole'"

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

I am building an asp.net core 8.0 console application which integrate with SharePoint online, and I want to enable logging, here is my full code:-

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using PnP.Core.QueryModel;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tenantId = "0000";
            var clientId = "000";
            var certificatePath = @"c:\C0000.pfx";
            var certificatePassword = "0000";

            // Initialize a new service collection
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            // Load the certificate
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            // Configure logging
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddConsole();
            });

            // Add and configure PnP Core SDK
            serviceCollection.AddPnPCore(options =>
            {
                options.PnPContext.GraphFirst = true; // Set true if you prefer to use Graph over CSOM when possible
               // options.HttpRequests.UserAgent = "ISV|Contoso|ProductX";
                options.Sites.Add("SiteToWorkWith", new PnPCoreSiteOptions
                {
                    SiteUrl = "https://*******",
                    AuthenticationProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(clientId, tenantId, certificate)
                });
            });

            // Build the service provider
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Use the service provider to get the IPnPContextFactory instance
            var pnpContextFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPnPContextFactory>();

            // Now you can use the IPnPContextFactory to get a PnPContext and perform operations
            var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith");
            // Assume the fields where not yet loaded, so loading them with the list
            var workOrderList = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                                 p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                               p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                               p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                               p => p.Title));
            await workOrderList.LoadAsync(p => p.Items);
            var inMemortWorkOrderList = workOrderList.Items.AsRequested();
            
            
            
            
            int i = 0;
            var t = "";
            // Do a paged retrieval of the list items
            await foreach (var listItem in workOrderList.Items)
            {
                // Do something with the list item
                t= listItem["Created"].ToString();
                i++;
            }

            

            // Example operation: Print the title of the SharePoint site
            // Explicitly load the Title property of the Web
            await context.Web.LoadAsync(w => w.Title);

            Console.WriteLine($"Site title: {context.Web.Title}"+ i);

            // Ensure to dispose the context
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole' and no accessible extension method 'AddConsole' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggingBuilder' could be found
```

on:-

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConsole();
});
```

any advice? my main idea is that i want to trace the requests that are been sent by my console application to be able to optimized it when needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you add the following Nuget package to your project:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`

by either using Visual Studio or executing

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`

from a command line